# Get data from two different tables in the same query

Tags: php, sql, left-join

I'm starting to learn php. I'm able to extract the list of CD from the SQL query in [in this table][1] but there's another query which contains the Category which is linked via ID in this table.

How do I get all the columns in the same result set using one query?

```
 <?php
    include 'database_conn.php';    

    $sql = "SELECT id, title, year, price FROM table_cd"; 
    $queryresult = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)
    or die (mysqli_error($conn));       


    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryresult)) {
        $iid = $row['id'];
        $title = $row['title'];
        $year = $row['year'];
        $price = $row['price'];

        echo "<div> 
        <a href = \"editCDForm.php?itemCode=$iid\">$title</a> 
        </div>\n";
        echo $row['year'];
        echo $row['price'];
    }

?>
```

editCDForm.php:

```
<?php

$code = $_GET['itemCode']; 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_cd WHERE table_category.ID = $code
JOIN table_category ON (table_category.Desc = table_cd.ID)";

?>
```

Comment: show both the table's structure.

Comment: So you are learning PHP and SQL at the same time? Maybe it would be a good idea to learn one after the other.

Comment: @Niranjan, it's in the link CD List & CD category..

Comment: @Thorsten .. sadly for my part-time course, it's a rush as we have to learn  many stuff together..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) which allows you to merge the rows from two or more tables into the same result set.

You can modify your query as illustrated below, by using a **LEFT** `JOIN` of the `nmc_cd` table and the `nmc_category` table on the `catID` column, as the common primary attribute between them, giving you the desired result set...

```
$sql = "SELECT nmc_cd.CDID, nmc_cd.CDTitle, nmc_cd.CDYear,
               nmc_cd.CDPrice, nmc_category.catDesc
        FROM nmc_cd
        JOIN nmc_category on nmc_cd.catID = nmc_cd.catID";
```

Here's a nice article that may help you [visualize what a JOIN looks like](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) in your SQL.

Syntax for joins:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON (table2.colunmname = table1.columnname)
```

Comment: Thank you so much ... the article is useful as i was trying out the different kind of JOIN

Comment: Sorry I was trying to try to sort the sql result by CDTitle and I was trying to put "ORDER BY nmc_cd.CDTitle" within the sql command. Somehow it isn't working....

Comment: order by should be the last clause, i mean after join add order by.

Comment: Thanks, i did try that by putting it at the last but somehow the result shows  a lot of repeated result..

Comment: use `GROUP BY nmc_cd.CDID`. First group by, then order by.

Comment: Thanks... just wondering the reason to use GROUP BY is because it's grabbing data from two different table ?

Comment: Yes, Because of that your data gets duplicated. So we should use `GROUP BY`

Comment: Sorry to trouble you, I was again trying to explore the JOIN for the 2nd portion of the php. It doesn't seem to be able to get the data from the nmc_category

Comment: Sorry i didnt get you.. Please add the query in your question.

Comment: I'm sorry, in the 1st portion I have the  <a href = \"editCDForm.php?itemCode=$iCDID\">$CDTitle</a>  publish in hyperlink which is linked to the 2nd portion. In the 2nd portion I'm trying to show the result also from the 2nd table using JOIN nmc_category"; but it doesn't show the same

Comment: It's in the question just below the picture under editCDForm.php
....The error I got -> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN nmc_category' at line 2

Comment: @DoranL you cant just tel `join table_name` use `on` and mention the columns on which you want to join

Comment: Thanks I try that but also got the same error. I was trying -> JOIN nmc_category on catDesc = nmc_category.catDesc";

Comment: you are doing it wrong, just have a look to the like provided in answer.

Comment: what i don't understand the part of the $code = $_GET['itemCode'];  where it trys to grab the select hyperlink from previous php. Using the $code it was trying to return the sql result.  It seems the 1st part of the php JOIN does not work here in the editCDForm.php

Comment: i ll add join syntax in my answer, please refer that.

Comment: Thank you.. it seems WHERE CDID = $code cannot coexist with JOIN table_name ON  ? I had to remove either one for it to run

Comment: add tablename.column name in where condition. A good practice while using joins.

Comment: Thanks, i try to be as specific as possible. I have updated the question with the code but still getting error. Would there be any issue using the $code ?

Comment: you are trying to match description with id, i think thats the issue.

Comment: hmmm, but if i need to store the result from the hyperlink, it have to be a id.

Comment: that's correct, why r u joining based on description??

Comment: Honestly, now is only my 3rd week of PHP class. I was thinking how do I display the CatDesc column using $_GET. This might avoid using description

Comment: I was researching ... Can I use the sql command "SELECT ..... AS .....FROM ..." instead ?

Comment: For what he asking this??

Comment: Sorry what do you mean ? he refers to ? I'm just trying to find other ways such as using SQL Aliases since it's not working

Comment: It's you are, ur... I mean for what you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

use can get the data from both tables when joining them:

```
 $sql = "SELECT FT.CDID, FT.CDTitle, FT.CDYear, FT.CDPrice,
 ST.catDesc FROM nmc_cd AS FT  LEFT JOIN nmc_category as ST ON     
 FT.catID=ST.catID";
```